# Как создать и сохранить файл в js на клиенте

Tags: javascript, файловая-система

Есть html-страница:

```
<input id='input' />
<button onclick='saveFile()'>Save<button>
```

Скрипт:

```
function saveFile(){
    var data = document.getElementById('input').value;
    //...create txt file with data
    //..save file on client
}
```

Файл должен сохраняться в "Загрузки" по-умолчанию

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

Все оказалось возможным:

```js
function saveFile() {
  var data = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var a = document.getElementById("linkForSavingFiles");
  var file = new Blob([data], {
    type: 'plain/text'
  });
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = 'file.txt';
  a.click();
}
```

```html
<input id='input' />
<button onclick='saveFile()'>Save</button>
<a href='' id='linkForSavingFile' style='display:none' />
```